# string.h:29:8: error: expected identifier

Tags: ssl, nginx, libressl

I'm trying to compile nginx with custom openssl »libressl« using this script: https://gist.github.com/Belphemur/3c022598919e6a1788fc

Everything works fine using libressl 2.1.1.
Problem is that libressl 2.1.1 has some security issues, which have been resolved by newer releases.
However I can't get the build to work with libressl 2.1.2 or libressl 2.1.3 (latest version).

The issue I get:

```
..
cc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I /tmp/build/pcre-8.36 -I /tmp/build/libressl-2.1.2/.openssl/include -I objs \
        -o objs/src/core/nginx.o \
        src/core/nginx.c
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:635:0,
                 from /tmp/build/libressl-2.1.2/.openssl/include/string.h:6,
                 from src/os/unix/ngx_linux_config.h:27,
                 from src/core/ngx_config.h:26,
                 from src/core/nginx.c:8:
/tmp/build/libressl-2.1.2/.openssl/include/string.h:29:8: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘__extension__’
 char * strndup(const char *str, size_t maxlen);
        ^
make[1]: *** [objs/src/core/nginx.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/build/nginx-1.7.9'
make: *** [build] Error 2
All done.
..
```

What's the problem & how to resolve it?
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the creator of the script you use to build Nginx with LibreSSL.

It is now corrected, the previous way to build and use libressl doesn't work with previous version of the script. (Simply copying all the include and stripping the lib)

The script now install libressl in a set directory and give it to nginx, this way, all the include not needed to use the library (like this string.h) is not part of the building process of nginx.

Answer (score 1):

`strndup` is provided in `string.h`. You don't need to provide it here:

```
/tmp/build/libressl-2.1.2/.openssl/include/string.h:29:8: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘__extension__’
char * strndup(const char *str, size_t maxlen);
```

I would delete the copy of `string.h` from the sources, and use the platform's supplied `string.h` for `strndup`.

As a matter of fact, I don't know where that `string.h` is coming from because its not present on my system (and I regularly build and use the latest OpenSSL):

```
$ find /usr/local/ssl/ -name string.h
$ find /usr/local/ssl/ -name *.h
/usr/local/ssl/include/openssl/rc4.h
/usr/local/ssl/include/openssl/crypto.h
/usr/local/ssl/include/openssl/ts.h
/usr/local/ssl/include/openssl/ecdsa.h
/usr/local/ssl/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
...
```

---

> I'm trying to compile nginx with custom openssl »libressl« using this script: https://gist.github.com/Belphemur/3c022598919e6a1788fc

OK, this can be a pain as I've had to do similar with nginx (FIPS validated OpenSSL).

The easiest way to handle it is build OpenSSL from sources and install it into `/usr/local/ssl`. Then, grep nginx's files for `-lcrypto` and `-lssl`. When you find them, replace them with the static archive of OpenSSL:

- change `-lcrypto` to `/usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a`
- change `-lssl` to `/usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a`

And drop the `-L` related to OpenSSL.

This will ensure you use your version of OpenSSL at compile time and run time without the need for `LD_PRELOAD` and `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` tricks. It will just always work.